# ondelete is not allowed on sybase

Tags: eclipse, maven, liquibase

liquibase documentation says it's possible ondelete with sybase. However, when I try an ondelete, I get the following message: ondelete is not allowed on sybase.

documentation: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/add_foreign_key_constraint.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Sybase' is not a database - it is a brand, with multiple databases that have some differences between them. Specifically Sybase ASE (now called SAP ASE) does not support 'ON XXX' clauses with constraints, but Sybase SQL Anywhere (now SAP SQL Anywhere) does.